# Having trouble creating an array of character strings. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write a program that takes a date and then converts it into the day of the week.

I think the main problem I'm having is that I'm not creating the array for the names of the week correctly and as a result, I'm not able to pass it back into the main function to print out.

Here is my code. I apologize in advance if it's messy, I'm teaching myself to code via books and haven't been doing this too long!

Any help would be very appreciated, thank you so much :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct DATE
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};


int main (void)
{
    int  N;

    char day;

    struct DATE date;

    int nConvert(struct DATE date);

    char dayFinder(int N);

    printf("Okay, choose your date:\n");
    scanf("%i:%i:%i", &date.day, &date.month, &date.year); //takes the date and creates a variable withing the DATE struct

    N = nConvert(date); //go convert the date into an integer

    day = dayFinder(N); //go convert N and turn it into a day of the week

    // now we can print out the day of the week that we created in dayFinder
    printf("The day of the week of %i, %i, %i is: %i%i%i\n", date.day, date.month, date.year, day[0], day[1], day[3]);
}


int nConvert(struct DATE N)
{
    int gee(struct DATE); //declare function to get gee and eff(required for conversion equation)
    int eff(struct DATE); 

    int f = eff(N); //call the functions so the outputs can be put into the equation for 'result'
    int g = gee(N);

    int result = (1461 * f) / 4 + (153 * g) / 5 + N.day; //store the result of the equation into a 'result'

    return result; //go put result back into main, will be called 'N'
}


int eff(struct DATE work)
{
    if(work.month <= 2)
    {
        work.year = work.year - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        work.year = work.year;
    }
    return work.year;
}


int gee(struct DATE work)
{
    if(work.month <= 2)
    {
        work.month = work.month + 13;
    }
    else
    {
        work.month = work.month + 1;
    }
    return work.month;
}

char dayFinder(int n)
{
    int convert = (n - 621049) % 7; //convert N sent from main, into integer called converter. 
                                    //we will now have a number that conincides with the day of the week

    char days[7]; //create an array of character strings for each day of the week

    days[0] = {'S', 'u', 'n'};
    days[1] = {'M', 'o', 'n'};
    days[2] = {'T', 'u', 'e'};
    days[3] = {'W', 'e', 'd'};
    days[4] = {'T', 'h', 'u'};
    days[5] = {'F', 'r', 'i'};
    days[6] = {'S', 'a', 't'};

      //now we match the int convert to the right day of the week, then return it back into 'main'
      if(convert == 0)
      {
          return days[0];
      }
      if(convert == 1)
      {
          return days[1];
      }
      if(convert == 2)
      {
          return days[2];
      }
      if(convert == 3)
      {
          return days[3];
      }
      if(convert == 4)
      {
          return days[4];
      }
      if(convert == 5)
      {
          return days[5];
      }
      if(convert == 6)
      {
          return days[6];
      }
}
```

Comment: Don't declare functions inside functions, it's normal to declare them in the global scope because functions are meant to be called from everywhere.

Comment: Look into the difference between a string and a `char`.  You have an array of `char`, not an array of strings or of `char` arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm familiar with this book: Programming In C 4th edition by Stephen Kochan.

Here's a way to complete the exercise without directly using pointers or strings. It uses the switch statement to print the text (strings).

```
/* exercise 8.4 from Programming in C, 4th edition

   the book states in this exercise that August 8, 2004 was a Tuesday;
   actually it was a Sunday    

   exercise 8.2 in the book, on which this exercise is based, also contains
   an error -- there are 198 elapsed days (not 202 days) between August 8,
   2004 and February 22, 2005
*/

#include <stdio.h>

struct date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

int f (int year, int month)
{
    int value;

    if ( month <= 2 )
        value = year - 1;
    else
        value = year;

    return value;
}

int g (int month)
{
    int value;

    if ( month <= 2 )
        value = month + 13;
    else
        value = month + 1;

    return value;
}

int calculateN (struct date d)
{
    return 1461 * f (d.year, d.month) / 4 + 153 * g (d.month) / 5 + d.day;
} 

int main (void)
{
    struct date date1;        

    printf("\nOkay, choose your date (day, month, year): ");
    scanf("%i%i%i", &date1.day, &date1.month, &date1.year);

    printf ("\nday of the week for %i/%i/%i is ", date1.day, date1.month, date1.year);

    switch ((calculateN (date1) - 621049) % 7)
    {
        case 0:
            printf ("Sunday");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf ("Monday");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf ("Tuesday");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf ("Wednesday");
            break;
        case 4:
            printf ("Thursday");
            break;
        case 5:
            printf ("Friday");
            break;
        case 6:
            printf ("Saturday");
            break;
        default:
            printf ("error ");
            break;
    }

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 important problems with your code, that reveal a serious problem in undrstanding basic concepts

1. Your declaration of `char day[7]` is not what you think.

   A `char` in this language is not a *string* nor an array. Your `char day[7]` is an array of 7 bytes only, you can't store 7 *strings* as you apparently want to.

   You need `char *day[7]` which is an array of 7 pointers, but looking at the rest of your function there is absolutely no need for an array.

   You could use the array to avoid the many `if` statements using string literals, because string literals are stored in a place in memory that allows to return them from functions even if they were declared as local variables to the functions, but in general you CAN'T return addresses (*or pointers*) local variables, because they are only allocated within the stack frame of the function where you declare them, and when the function returns the stack pointer is reset to it's position before the function call thus, all the data that was local to the function is no longer accessible, although it might still be there but there is no guarantee, so you SHOULD never do it.

   A working and good function to do what you want would be

   ```
   const char *get_day_name(int week_day)
   {
        const char *days[7] = {"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};
        return days[week_day];
   }
   ```
2. You return the value of a character which then you try to access it as if it was an array, your compiler is not letting you do that, so the program is not compiling for sure.
3. Your "*strings*" all lack the terminating `null` byte, every string in [c](/questions/tagged/c) must be terminated with a `null` byte `'\0'`, all the functions that expect *strings* need this byte to tell where is the end of the string, if it is not present then passing it to a function like `printf()` would cause *undefined behavior*, although it appears that your intention is to print each character of the day string, and in that case you will not need the terminating `null` byte, you should get used to the fact that strings need this byte. It's a common source of problems for new programmers to the [c](/questions/tagged/c) language.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly, this is actually an exercise in 'Programming in C' and this comes BEFORE the chapter on 'Character Strings' so yes I'm having a lot of trouble. I know I'll learn about this stuff in detail later on, I'm just not sure if I'm able to complete it WITHOUT all of this. Unless I'm supposed to do it without the use of character strings.

Comment: I also haven't gotten to pointers so I can't use those unfortunately!

Comment: @MattCleary No, you can't AVOID those. One way or the other you will use pointers. Whethere you know they are pointers or not.

Comment: haha oh I know I have to use them eventually! I'm just assuming that the book wants me to solve the exercises without them seeing as it hasn't taught me them yet and assumes I have no prior knowledge of them.

Is it not possible to do so otherwise?

Comment: @MattCleary Have you seen any example with a `"static string literal"`, like `printf("Hello World!\n");`? There you go, `"Hello World!\n"` is a character string, and a pointer too. So you cannot avoid them even for a very simple *Hello World*. Learning how to handle them, that's another problem that surely the book covers later.

Comment: I guess conceptually I would have seen them. But I don't know anything about the syntax and all the *'s and &'s etc yet. Unless it's the &'s used in scanf

Comment: Is it possible to complete the exercise I'm working on without having knowledge of pointer syntax (* and &) etc?

Answer (score 0):

You had a bunch of problems in your code. I cleaned up some of them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{

    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

} DATE;

int nConvert(DATE N);
int eff(DATE work);
int gee(DATE work);
char* getName(int week_day);

int main (void)
{
    int  N;

    char* day;

    DATE date;

    printf("Okay, choose your day:\n");
    scanf("%i:%i:%i", &date.day,  &date.month, &date.year ); 

    N = nConvert(date); //go convert the date into an integer

    day = getName(N); //go convert N and turn it into a day of the week

    // now we can print out the day of the week that we created in dayFinder
    printf("The day of the week of %i, %i, %i is: %s\n", date.day, date.month, date.year, day);

    return 0;
}


int nConvert(DATE N)
{

    int f = eff(N); //call the functions so the outputs can be put into the equation for 'result'
    int g = gee(N);

    int result = (1461 * f) / 4 + (153 * g) / 5 + N.day; //store the result of the equation into a 'result'

    return result; //go put result back into main, will be called 'N'
}


int eff(DATE work)
{
    if(work.month <= 2)
    {
        work.year = work.year - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        work.year = work.year;
    }
    return work.year;
}


int gee( DATE work)
{
    if(work.month <= 2)
    {
        work.month = work.month + 13;
    }
    else
    {
        work.month = work.month + 1;
    }
    return work.month;
}

char* getName(int day)
{
     const char* days[7] = {"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};
     return days[day%7];
}
```

If you REALLY REALLY want to avoid the *, then I guess you could do this:

```
int main (void)
{
    int  N;

    DATE date;

    printf("Okay, choose your day:\n");
    scanf("%i:%i:%i", &date.day,  &date.month, &date.year ); 

    N = nConvert(date); //go convert the date into an integer

    char names[7][3] = {
        {'S', 'u', 'n'},
        {'M', 'o', 'n'},
        {'T', 'u', 'e'},
        {'W', 'e', 'd'},
        {'T', 'h', 'u'},
        {'F', 'r', 'i'},
        {'S', 'a', 't'}
    };
    int dayNum = N%7;

    // now we can print out the day of the week that we created in dayFinder
    printf("The day of the week of %i, %i, %i is: %c%c%c\n", date.day, date.month, date.year, names[dayNum][0], names[dayNum][1], names[dayNum][2]);

    return 0;
}
```

However you are still using pointers and you can't really avoid them.

Comment: Thank you. I have not come across pointers in the book that I am working from yet, however. Is it possible to complete this exercise without them?

Comment: @MattCleary Maybe if you did what is done in the background for a 2D array by hand: first three chars are first string, next three are second string, etc. other (not so good) idea that comes to mind is array1 for first char of each string, array2 for second chars, etc